# Copy text to specific line

Tags: c#

I didn't get why it isn't working.. 
Error shows like,  `newArraylist (line 13);` `newSreamReader (line 14, 24)`
  does not exist.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
namespace InsertLineInTextFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string strTextFileName = "file.txt";
            int iInsertAtLineNumber = 2;
            string strTextToInsert = "Amudha";
            ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
            StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(strTextFileName);
            string line;
            while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null) lines.Add(line);
            rdr.Close();
            if (lines.Count > iInsertAtLineNumber) lines.Insert(iInsertAtLineNumber, strTextToInsert);

            else
                lines.Add(strTextToInsert);
            StreamWriter wrtr = new StreamWriter(strTextFileName);
            foreach (string strNewLine in lines) wrtr.WriteLine(strNewLine);
            wrtr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with `new ArrayList()` and `new SreamReader(strTextFileName)`

Comment: @QuentinRoger .. Where should i mention it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to think over what you're going to achieve; *reverse engeniering* (alas!) says

> insert **strTextToInsert** at **iInsertAtLineNumber** line of **fileName** file
>   (or *add* the text if the file is *too short*)

Then implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO; 
using System.Linq;

...
string fileName = "file.txt";
int iInsertAtLineNumber = 2;
string strTextToInsert = "Amudha";

List<String> lines = File
  .ReadLines(fileName)
  .ToList();

if (lines.Count > iInsertAtLineNumber)
  lines.Insert(iInsertAtLineNumber, strTextToInsert);
else
  lines.Add(strTextToInsert);

File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);
```

Please, do not use *obsolete* class `ArrayList` but `List<T>` (`List<String>` in the question). Often `File.ReadLines` and `File.WriteAllLines` are more *readable* and *easier to maintain* than `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter`.

Comment: @user6435267: Just in the very begining of the question: "I tried to insert a line..." then your code; finally, your problem - (please, not "it isn't working" - if it had worked you didn't posted the question) - *compile time error* at line #... ("..."); quote the message the compiler showed

Comment: @user6435267: I'm sorry for *typo*, it should be `.ReadLines(fileName)`; see my edit, please

Comment: Thanks bro.. I owe you.. And another thing.. Can we call another program to run within a program.  And when the second one starts running the first one should close..  Thanks in advance..

Comment: @user6435267: in order to run another problem, please, have a look at  `System.Diagnostics.Process` class; to close the current program, just *return* from the `Main` method

Comment: Can you please give it in an example.  I m kinda rookie in this.. Thanks

Comment: @user6435267: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user6435267: Then in the `File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);` put the right file's name instead of current `fileName`; you may want `Path` class to extract directory name, combine path parts

Comment: string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"C:\Users\doc\", file.txt);                 what do you think of this..  I tried it but getting an error of 'Sololearn.Program doesn't contain a definition for. txt'....

Comment: @user6435267: You, probably, want `string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "file.txt");`

Comment: What if there are different files with same file names in different folders..?

Comment: @user6435267: `File.WriteAllLines` *overrides* a file if it exists; if you want to append - `File.AppendAllLines`

Comment: in the program,  it mentioned,  Environment.CurrentDirectory.... If file exists in different folder,  How should i write the code..?

Comment: @user6435267: `Path.Combine(SomeOtherDirectory, "file.txt");`

Comment: @user6435267: put actual directory instead of `SomeOtherDirectory`: e.g. `Path.Combine(@"C:\MyTests\MyDir", "file.txt");`